# Horizontal scrollview with dynamic images

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

How to do if i want an images in scrollview(Dynamically)...

Here is the soucre...

```
 <HorizontalScrollView 
   android:id="@+id/horizontalview" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/li"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

(not going for album viewer)

Comment: Add LinaerLayout in Horizontal Orientation and add one by one image into it and at the end add this LinearLayout to Horizontal ScrollView

Comment: here is the addition @M D

Answer (score 2):

```
void setThumbviewImages(int position)
    {
//set margin between two images.

        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);

//universal image loader 
options1 = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.resetViewBeforeLoading()
.build();

    int n = arrl_product.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Item item = arrItem.get(i);
        Product p = arrl_product.get(i);
//custom layout for each imageview. which i required
        final View view_lyt = lyt_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_com_thumb_img, null);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view_lyt.findViewById(R.id.non_com_grid_img);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(img_width, img_height));

        animateFirstListener1 = new Constant.AnimateFirstDisplayListener(new ProgressBar(Act_Comm.this));

        final String image_url = p.arr_images.get(0).image_method;
        imageView.setTag(i);

        imageLoader1.displayImage(image_url, imageView, options1, animateFirstListener1);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
            }
        });
        lin_thumb.addView(view_lyt, params);
    }

}
```

**My XML File**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/com_iview_horizontalScrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/com_iview_lin_imageview"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Second lyt_com_thumb_img.xml layout**

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/thumb_main_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/non_com_grid_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Banku here i have add some extra code please ignore it.
And please accept answer if it is helpfull for you.

Comment: how to highlight the image view in horizantal scrollview@Bhavesh jethani

Comment: You can set by defualt 0 position as highlighted by changing background and any other approach .. and when clicking on image view you need to set all imageview as defualt view and selected image with different background. now how to get all images .... you get get all images from horizonatal scroll using getChildAt and getChildCount. specially in your code you will get linear layout from horizonalscrollview by getChildAt(0) and by using Linear Layout you can get All the images by using for loop and and getChildAt().

Comment: can you give any sample code because its very urgent@Bhavesh Jethani